# Geary's index of spatial autocorrelation

Tags: spatial-statistics, spatial-index, autocorrelation

Does anyone knows If there is a way to calculate Geary's index of spatial autocorrelation on open source gis?

Comment: Answers to this question also appear at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/what-are-sources-for-current-geo-statistical-analysis-classes-events-open-or-pr (a thread about sources of information on spatial statistics).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this question [(How to implement Spatial Autocorrelation using QGIS or PostgreSQL (or any free application)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59614/how-to-implement-spatial-autocorrelation-using-qgis-or-postgresql-or-any-free-a)) and look at programmatic solutions like R.
QGIS may be another option as well.

[This website](http://www.fao.org/docrep/006/y4841e/y4841e08.htm) outlines different formulas and measures for spatial autocorrelation that may also be of interest to you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

- the Python module [PySAL](http://pysal.readthedocs.org/en/v1.7/): [Spatial Autocorrelation](https://pythonhosted.org/PySAL/users/tutorials/autocorrelation.html). You can use it in the Python console of QGIS or in a script in the Processing Toolbox
- [R](http://www.r-project.org/) ([Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R: analysis with R](http://books.google.be/books?id=4gg8yx_lcj0C&pg=PA356&lpg=PA356&dq=%22grass%20GIS%22%20%22spatial%20autocorrelation%22&source=bl&ots=yAaD-v602F&sig=LnKJaM_5fYGC0aGVCNOholwb6hY&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=BwHAU9SbMeeO0AW8mYCACQ&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=%22grass%20GIS%22%20%22spatial%20autocorrelation%22&f=false), [“The Problem of Spatial Autocorrelation:” forty years on](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spdep/vignettes/CO69.pdf), [Geary's C test for spatial autocorrelation](http://books.google.be/books?id=4gg8yx_lcj0C&pg=PA356&lpg=PA356&dq=%22grass+GIS%22+%22spatial+autocorrelation%22&source=bl&ots=yAaD-v602F&sig=LnKJaM_5fYGC0aGVCNOholwb6hY&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=BwHAU9SbMeeO0AW8mYCACQ&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=%22grass%20GIS%22%20%22spatial%20autocorrelation%22&f=false), for example, but there are many others)
- [gvSIG](http://books.google.be/books?id=4gg8yx_lcj0C&pg=PA356&lpg=PA356&dq=%22grass+GIS%22+%22spatial+autocorrelation%22&source=bl&ots=yAaD-v602F&sig=LnKJaM_5fYGC0aGVCNOholwb6hY&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=BwHAU9SbMeeO0AW8mYCACQ&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=%22grass%20GIS%22%20%22spatial%20autocorrelation%22&f=false) and [OpenJUMP](http://www.gvsig.org/web) with the Sextante Toolbox